# Do we say "He littered candy wrappers all over the floor" or "He littered the floor with candy wrapper"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> [litter](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/litter_2) [transitive, usually passive, intransitive] to leave
> things in a place, making it look untidy
>
> **be littered with something** The floor was littered with papers.
>
> He was arrested for littering.

It seems that the dictionary suggests us to say

*The floor is littered with candy wrappers.*

or

*He littered the floor with candy wrappers.*

My question is that:

We can say "**He left/scattered/dropped/threw candy wrappers all over the floor**"

But why can't we say "**He littered candy wrappers all over the floor**"?

Comment: What has that poor boy done now?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, he has been doing a lot of crazy things

Answer (score 1):

Here's another dictionary definition:
[American Heritage Dictionary "litter"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=litter)

2. To make untidy by discarding rubbish carelessly: *Someone had littered the beach with food wrappers.*
3. To scatter about: *littered towels all over the locker room.*

That definition shows both uses, that is, with the scattered material as object, or with the dirtied space as object, so you can use either of your example sentences:

"He littered the floor with candy wrappers."
or
"He littered candy wrappers all over the floor.

There's a slightly stronger focus on the direct object, whichever it is.

Comment: Why many native speakers say "He littered candy wrappers all over the floor" is not valid. It's like you make the candy wrappers dirty when you "litter them".

Comment: I would say that the meanings 'drop litter in a place' and 'make a place untidy by dropping litter' were much more common than 'drop something as litter', so much so that people are unsure whether the last one is valid.